Как можно перевести большой файл json, но только один из параметров?
Есть ли какой то скрипт который переведет реплики людей с английского на русский бесплатно). Данные находится в json файлах и там много разных параметров и надо переводить только определенные параметры. По типу вот такого решения

Пишите скрипт на чём вы там умеете, который из большого джейсона делает маленький только с нужными данными, а потом переводите его с помощью готового решения.
Ну, и потом можно обратно перевод вставить в большой джейсон, если нужно.
